# error import cx_Freeze how i can resolve?

Tags: python

import cx_Freeze
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    import cx_Freeze
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Freeze'

Comment: We're missing information. See: [ask], [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed `cx_freeze` with pip ?
If yes please try to upgrade `cx_freeze`

`pip install --upgrade cx_freeze`

If none of this not working, please try the following:

Run `python.exe cxfreeze-postinstall` from the command prompt, two batch files are being created in the Python scripts directory:

`cxfreeze.bat`

`cxfreeze-quickstart.bat`

From that moment on, you should be able to run cx_freeze.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with python 3.11 compatibility.  I had the same issue, so installing a development version of cx_freeze solved the issue for me.

```
pip install --pre --extra-index-url https://marcelotduarte.github.io/packages/ cx_Freeze
```